# Looping over an enumerating list - how to skip a number?

Tags: python, list, loops, logic, enumerate

In the following simple loop example, I would like to end up with 12 axes names sequentially by skipping one of the entries in a list of 13 data columns.

```
question_list=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6a', 'Q6b', 'Q7', 'Q8','Q9', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12']

for c, z in enumerate(question_list):
    if '6b' not in z:
        axis_names='ax_corr_'+str(c+1)
    print(axis_names)
```

Instead, I get the entry `"ax_corr_6"` two times in the resulting list `axis_names`. I do not understand why the entry for 6b was not simply skipped and the enumeration advanced to 7. It leads me to believe I don't quite understand how to encode this simple logic in Python. Can anyone clarify why this happens and how to achieve a list that skips `'Q6a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're trying to print the index except when `6b` will be miss matched. Try a debug and print `Z` it really works or not. Find the output of my code and will be seen `6b` is skipping.

```
for c, z in enumerate(question_list):
    if '6b' not in z:
        print('For '+z + ' ax_corr_'+str(c+1))
```

For better understanding follow up the output where `6b` is skipped.

```
For Q1 ax_corr_1
For Q2 ax_corr_2
For Q3 ax_corr_3
For Q4 ax_corr_4
For Q5 ax_corr_5
For Q6a ax_corr_6
For Q7 ax_corr_8
For Q8 ax_corr_9
For Q9 ax_corr_10
For Q10 ax_corr_11
For Q11 ax_corr_12
For Q12 ax_corr_13
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem:

```
question_list=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6a', 'Q6b', 'Q7', 'Q8',
               'Q9', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12']

for c, z in enumerate(question_list):
    if '6b' not in z:
        # added the z-value to the string for clarity
        axis_names='ax_corr_'+str(c+1)+"_"+z
    print(axis_names)                        # this will print Q6a' once on its turn and
                                             # once the old value one turn later when the
                                             # conditional skips the value Q6b
```

Solution:

- indent print inside the if-conditional so you do not see the double output
- or use a list comp and print that:

  ```
  lc = [f"ax_corr_{c}_{z}" for c, z in enumerate(question_list,1)           
       if '6b' not in z]
  print(lc)
  ```

Output:

```
 ['ax_corr_1_Q1',  'ax_corr_2_Q2',   'ax_corr_3_Q3',   'ax_corr_4_Q4', 
  'ax_corr_5_Q5',  'ax_corr_6_Q6a',  'ax_corr_8_Q7',   'ax_corr_9_Q8', 
  'ax_corr_10_Q9', 'ax_corr_11_Q10', 'ax_corr_12_Q11', 'ax_corr_13_Q12']
```

You'll need the list for the naming of your axes print eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right you want to skip '6b'

enumerate traverses through your list where c is the index and z is the value at index c.
hence you need to compare the element and not finding it in a list. So replacing "not in" with "!=" would do the job.

```
question_list=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6a', 'Q6b', 'Q7', 'Q8','Q9', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12']

for c, z in enumerate(question_list):
    if '6b' != z:
        axis_names='ax_corr_'+str(c+1)
    print(axis_names)
```

Maybe it would be easier to remove the '6b' from the list before iterating:

```
question_list.remove('6b')
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to this:

```
question_list=['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6a', 'Q6b', 'Q7', 'Q8','Q9', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12']

for c, z in enumerate(question_list):
    if '6b' not in z:
        axis_names='ax_corr_'+str(c+1)
        print(axis_names)
```